# Wordpress Pagination not showing when using get_posts()

Tags: wordpress

I am working wordpress search using Relevenssi search plugin. I need to add functionality for empty search term search. For that I am using below code in function.php

```
function rlv_hits_filter($hits) {
global $wp_query;
if (
    !$hits[1] &&
    isset( $wp_query->query_vars['post_type']) || 
    isset( $wp_query->query_vars['credentials']) ||
    isset( $wp_query->query_vars['zipcode'])
) {
    $args = array('post_type' => 'vendors','posts_per_page' => 15);
   $my_custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $hits[0] = get_posts( $my_custom_query->query_vars );
}
return $hits;
}
add_filter('relevanssi_hits_filter', 'rlv_hits_filter',1);
```

I have total 380 posts. But when i used the above code only 15 posts are showing and there is no pagination showing. Here is my pagination code also written in function.php

```
function bootstrap_pagination( $echo = true ) {
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; 
$pages = paginate_links( array(
        //'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type'  => 'array',
        'prev_next'   => true,
        'prev_text'    => __('&lt; Prev'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next &gt;'),
    )
);
if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
    $pagination = '<ul class="pagination">';
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $pagination .= "<li>$page</li>";
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';
    if ( $echo ) {
        echo $pagination;
    } else {
        return $pagination;
    }
    }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me how to solve this.

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the problem is with the `rlv_hits_filter` or `bootstrap_pagination`? We can't try your code because we don't have same set up as you, so we need as much information from you as possible so we can help.

Comment: I think bootstrap_pagination not getting values when use get_posts( $my_custom_query->query_vars );